# Position Divs in columns when using directives in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, position, styling

I know this question has been asked 100 different ways but i have not yet found an answer that works for me. Essentially i have 2  elements nested inside a wrapper , One of those inner  elements is essentially just a setup for an angular directive that pops an  element into DOM. It looks like this

```
<div class="panel-body" id="swfStage" style="width:320px; height:240px;background-color: #355E95;overflow: auto;white-space:nowrap  ">
    <div class="swfWrapper" style="width: 80%;display: inline-block;">
        <div tf-swf class="tf-container" tf-src="swfs/thin.swf" tf-min-version="11.0.0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="chatWrapper" style=style="width: 19%;display: inline-block;">It works</div>
</div>
```

The goal here is that the outer most  is a container for the two main inner 's ... I want those divs to be side by side

What i have here is giving me the two inner divs on top of each other.

Answer (score 1):

You just have a typo in your html:

```
style=style=
```

Should just be

```
style=
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that you could go about this while maintaining the structure of your HTML (but taking out the inline style definitions for cleanliness).

**HTML**

```
<div class="panel-body" id="swfStage">
    <div class="swfWrapper">
        <div tf-swf class="tf-container" tf-src="swfs/thin.swf" tf-min-version="11.0.0"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="chatWrapper">It works</div>
</div>
```

**Option 1: CSS for Table Styling Option**

```
.panel-body {
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background-color: #355E95;
    overflow: auto
    display: table;
}

.swfWrapper {
    width: 80%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}

.chatWrapper {
    width: 19%;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: green;
}
```

**Option 2: CSS for Positioning Option**

```
.panel-body {
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    background-color: #355E95;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.swfWrapper {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.chatWrapper {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3 [flex](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) [(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/WtEP4/1/):

```
.panel-body {
    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;
    background-color: #355e95;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
}

.swfWrapper {
    flex: 1 0 80%;
}

.chatWrapper {
    flex: 1 0 20%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```